# Scope variable not being assigned from a $http response inside a function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that many similar issues had been discussed here but not a single answer helped me with my specific issue. I have a function and I perform a $http get request inside it. I also pass a object as an argument in the function. On a successful response I see the correct data and I try to assign it to the outside variable that I'm passing. But data from the response doesn't seem to "escape" outside the function. The outside variable is also a scope variable. I don't use it directly because the function is supposed to be used by other controllers down the hierarchy.
Here's the function:

```
$scope.getUser = function (userID, userData) {
    var response = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: ("user/" + userID),
        responseType: "json"
    })
        .then(
        function (response) { //success
            return response.data;
        },
        function (response) { //error
            alert(response.data.message);
            return undefined;
        })
            .then(function (data) {
                userData = data;
            });
};
```

Basically I'm trying to assign the result to userData like this:

```
$scope.user = {} //in the beginning of the controller.
//.....
$scope.getUser(1, $scope.user);
```

and after that $scope.user is still untouched.
I also tried putting that inside **$apply** function but the result was still the same.
If I put $scope.user inside the function instead of the userData argument everything is ok but like I said, it's not the purpose of the function. It should be capable of working with any variable. I'm using angular ui router and the controller in which this function is located is on the top of the hierarchy and all other controllers should access it and use it to obtain a user from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying input parameter of a function would not guarantee that it also updates function's caller, and it is not a good programming pattern.

You may consider passing an update delegate to the function which contains the logic of updating the data you need.  For example, here is a revised getUser function

```js
$scope.getUser = function (userID, updateUserDataDelegate) {
    var response = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: ("user/" + userID),
        responseType: "json"
    }).then(
        function (response) { //success
            updateUserDataDelegate(response.data);
        },
        function (response) { //error
            alert(response.data.message);
            return undefined;
        }
    );
};


$scope.user = {} //in the beginning of the controller.

var updateScopeUserDelegate = function( userData ) {  $scope.user = userData; };
$scope.getUser(1, updateScopeUserDelegate);
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach mentioned in your question isn't a valid one and I would suggest you to wait for the results in your controller function to make any $scope assignments.

Give it a try

```
$scope.getUser = function (userID) {
    return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: ("user/" + userID),
        responseType: "json"
    }).then(function (results) {
        return results.data;
    });;
}

//and call it from your controller like

$scope.getUser(1).then(function (data){
    //perform any data validations here
    $scope.user = data;
});
```

Comment: Sorry but didn't help. This is actually almost the same as what I did but you just moved the final "then" outside the function

Comment: No, this is not the same. I am not passing any variable from my controller to the service and waiting for the service to return us the information. The manipulation with that data should be in the controller not in the service.

Comment: I understand. But it didn't work for me yet... The solution suggested by @Tianzhen Lin worked.